# is it possible to add uri parameters on a http callout using named credentials?

Tags: apex, rest-api, callout, apexrest

Context: I have to call, from a source org, a HttpGet method from a target org.
This method will return a list of records that match a certain value on a field, which I have to send from my source org.

I understand that a GET http request does not have a body. So, my idea was to send the value via parameters, but, if I set the endpoint like this

```
req.setEndpoint('callout:restResource')
```

How do I add the parameter? Is it possible to add it like this:

```
req.setEndpoint('callout:restResource' + '?value=someValue')
```

Or can I send the value on the header? like this

```
req.setHeader('value', someValue);
```

If neither of those work or are good practice, which ways can I send data?

Thanks!

Comment: `req.setEndpoint('callout:restResource' + '?value=someValue')` works fine as does the `setHeader`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP headers (via setHeader) are typically for things like an authorization token and such. "Application" level data are put into the query string. For example, if I wanted to search Google, I could either:

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest('callout:google/search/?q='+EncodingUtil.urlEncode(searchTerm,'utf-8'));
```

Or:

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest('callout:search?q='+EncodingUtil.urlEncode(searchTerm,'utf-8'));
```

Depending on if the base URL was defined as 'https://www.google.com' or 'https://www.google.com/search' (respectively).

Comment: Thank you, I have a question, is encoding the value on the query parameter a good practice?

Comment: @joacoiudica [Percent-encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) has reserved and unreserved characters. The former must always be encoded, while the latter should never be encoded. As such, unless you can guarantee your input has only unreserved characters (e.g. it's a Salesforce ID, restricted to alphanumeric characters, etc), you should use `urlEncode`. It's almost always a good idea to encode user input to avoid URL injections.

Comment: thank you very much for the info! I've learned a lot with your replies. I'll dig in on the docs!